# Displaying Flowcharts in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flowchart

I want to display some data relations (coming from an xml, for that matter) in asp.net as a flowchart.

It doesn't necessarily have to be a freeware (although it would be nice).
What do you recommend I use?

---

*Edit:*
Automatically arranging the node locations according to the relations would be a big advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't claim to be an expert in this, but I just spent a fair amount of time trolling around the web looking for such a tool. In the end, I found an awesome javascript engine for doing this:

**jsPlumb**: http://code.google.com/p/jsplumb/

It will take some work on your part, but the examples are very nice. It *should* be able to do everything you want.

Comment: Looks nice, I'll check it out.